# Why can't show data passed by getJSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, getjson

The test-json.php read the database , and prepare it in JSON format.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "guestbook"); 
$result=$conn->query("select * From lyb limit 2"); 
echo '[';
$i=0;
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){  ?>
 {title:"<?= $row['title'] ?>",
        content:"<?= $row['content'] ?>",
        author:"<?= $row['author'] ?>",
        email:"<?= $row['email'] ?>",
        ip:"<?= $row['ip'] ?>"}
<?php 
if(
$result->num_rows!=++$i) echo ',';   
}
echo ']'    
?>
```

For my database,`select * From lib limit 2` get the records.

```
title    | content   | author   | email            |ip
welcome1 | welcome1  | welcome1 | welcome1@tom.com |59.51.24.37
welcome2 | welcome2  | welcome2 | welcome2@tom.com |59.51.24.38
```

php -f /var/www/html/test-json.php

```
[ {title:"welcome1",
         content:"welcome1",
        author:"welcome1",
         email:"welcome1@tom.com",
        ip:"59.51.24.37"},
{title:"welcome2",
         content:"welcome2",
        author:"welcome2",
         email:"welcome2@tom.com",
        ip:"59.51.24.38"}]
```

`test-json.php` get some data in JSON format.

Now to callback the data and show it in the table.

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<h2 align="center">Ajax show data in table</h2>
<table>
    <tbody id="disp">
        <th>title</th>
        <th>content</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>ip</th>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script> 
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("test-json.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            var tr = "<tr><td>" + item.title + "</td>"    +
                        "<td>"  + item.content  + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.author  + "</td>"  +
                        "<td>"  + item.email  + "</td>"   +
                        "<td>"  + item.ip  + "</td></tr>"
            $("#disp").append(tr);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Type `127.0.0.1/test-json.html`, why no data created by `test-json.php` on a webpage?

What i get is as below:

```
Ajax show data in table
title   content author  email   ip
```

What i expect is as below:

```
Ajax show data in table
title   content author  email   ip
welcome1  welcome1  welcome1  welcome1@tom.com  59.51.24.37
welcome2  welcome2  welcome2  welcome2@tom.com  59.51.24.38
```

Comment: post your `PHP` code too.

Comment: Your `test-json.php` file is not producing valid JSON so it cannot be parsed. In JSON, object keys must be quoted. You should use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php) in your PHP to produce a valid string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the response from your PHP script is not valid JSON.

In JSON, object keys must be quoted.

Rather than try and roll-your-own JSON response, use `json_encode()` to do it for you. For example

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "guestbook"); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title, content, author, email, ip FROM lyb limit 2');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title, $content, $author, $email, $ip);
$result = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result[] = [
        'title'   => $title,
        'content' => $content,
        'author'  => $author,
        'email'   => $email,
        'ip'      => $ip
    ];
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

<sub>You don't have to use `prepare()` and `bind_result()`, that's just my preference when working with MySQLi.</sub>

This will produce something like

```
[
  {
    "title": "welcome1",
    "content": "welcome1",
    "author": "welcome1",
    "email": "welcome1@tom.com",
    "ip": "59.51.24.37"
  },
  {
    "title": "welcome2",
    "content": "welcome2",
    "author": "welcome2",
    "email": "welcome2@tom.com",
    "ip": "59.51.24.38"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of mistakes in your `PHP` code.

**Here's how things should be handled in the server-side(`PHP`):**

filename: `test-json.php`

1. Fetch the records from the database.
2. Populate an array(I named that array `$data` in the code below) with the records that are already fetched from the database.
3. Encode that array as `JSON` format and echo the result.

**Here's how things should be handled in the client-side(`JavaScript`):**

4. Make an `AJAX` request to the `test-json.php` file.
5. If that request has succeeded, then iterate over the returned `JSON` and populate a variable(I named it 'html') that will hold all the `HTML` code(along with the received data) that will be appended to the table.
6. Append that variable(that I named 'html') to the table, with that we gain performance as we access the `DOM` only once per `AJAX` request.

With all that being said, here's the solution:

**`PHP` code - filename: `test-json.php`:**

```
<?php
// use the column names in the 'SELECT' query to gain performance against the wildcard('*').
$conn = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "guestbook"); 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT `title`, `content`, `author`, `email`, `ip` FROM `lyb` limit 2"); 

// $data variable will hold the returned records from the database.
$data = [];

// populate $data variable.
// the '[]' notation(empty brackets) means that the index of the array is automatically incremented on each iteration.
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data[] = [
    'title'   => $row['title'],
    'content' => $row['content'],
    'author'  => $row['author'],
    'email'   => $row['email'],
    'ip'      => $row['ip']
  ];
}

// convert the $data variable to JSON and echo it to the browser.
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**`JavaScript` code**

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("test-json.php", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data,function(key, value){
            html += "<tr><td>" + value.title + "</td>"    +
                        "<td>"  + value.content  + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + value.author  + "</td>"  +
                        "<td>"  + value.email  + "</td>"   +
                        "<td>"  + value.ip  + "</td></tr>";

        });
        $("#disp").append(html);
    });
});
```

> [Learn more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) about `json_encode` function.

Hope I pushed you further.